# PHP curl > SOAP got data having problems getting information

Tags: php, soap, curl, xml-parsing

I recently asked a different question about using SOAP with PHP but since that time got sick of the client server response never working. Instead I switched to cURL where I could specify everything and now I get a correct response.

My problem comes in getting information from this data. I have tried tutorials for the last 2 days and most of them I tried worked fine but when I apply the same methods to my own data I get empty results. I >Think<  its because of the xml tags using spaces in names or something like it I don't know.

If someone could point me in the right direct here it would be much appreciated. Like as simple as getting 1 piece of information showing me how, I don't need it all done for me. Thank you.

The XML return is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><FetchStockResponse xmlns="http://www.wics.nl"><FetchStockResult><DS><xs:schema id="rsVoorraad" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop"><xs:element name="rsVoorraad" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="" msprop:PROGRESS.brejected="False" msprop:PROGRESS.bdata_source_mod="False"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Voorraad" msdata:Locale="" msprop:PROGRESS.brejected="False" msprop:PROGRESS.bdata_source_mod="False" msprop:PROGRESS.errorString="" msprop:PROGRESS.bundo="True" msprop:PROGRESS.bimage_flag="False"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="ArtikelCode" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="0" msprop:PROGRESS.position="2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="ArtikelGroepCode" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="1" msprop:PROGRESS.position="3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="Omschrijving" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="2" msprop:PROGRESS.position="4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="VariantCode" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="3" msprop:PROGRESS.position="5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="Type" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="4" msprop:PROGRESS.position="6" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="Aantal" msprop:PROGRESS.init_value="0" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="5" msprop:PROGRESS.position="7" type="xs:decimal" default="0" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="OrderVoorraad" msdata:Locale="" msprop:PROGRESS.brejected="False" msprop:PROGRESS.bdata_source_mod="False" msprop:PROGRESS.errorString="" msprop:PROGRESS.bundo="True" msprop:PROGRESS.bimage_flag="False" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:annotation><xs:appinfo><msdata:Relationship name="relOrder" msdata:parent="Voorraad" msdata:child="OrderVoorraad" msdata:parentkey="Type ArtikelCode" msdata:childkey="Type ArtikelCode" /></xs:appinfo></xs:annotation><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="Type" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="0" msprop:PROGRESS.position="2" type="xs:string" /><xs:element name="ArtikelCode" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="1" msprop:PROGRESS.position="3" type="xs:string" /><xs:element name="VariantCode" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="2" msprop:PROGRESS.position="4" type="xs:string" /><xs:element name="Ordernummer" msprop:PROGRESS.init_value="0" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="3" msprop:PROGRESS.position="5" type="xs:int" default="0" /><xs:element name="Regelnummer" msprop:PROGRESS.init_value="0" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="4" msprop:PROGRESS.position="6" type="xs:int" default="0" /><xs:element name="Referentie" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="5" msprop:PROGRESS.position="7" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="Plaats" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="6" msprop:PROGRESS.position="8" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="Leverdatum" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="7" msprop:PROGRESS.position="9" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /><xs:element name="Aantal" msprop:PROGRESS.init_value="0" msprop:PROGRESS.user_order="8" msprop:PROGRESS.position="10" type="xs:decimal" default="0" minOccurs="0" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType><xs:unique name="idxOrderVoorraad" msdata:PrimaryKey="true"><xs:selector xpath=".//OrderVoorraad" /><xs:field xpath="Type" /><xs:field xpath="ArtikelCode" /><xs:field xpath="VariantCode" /><xs:field xpath="Ordernummer" /><xs:field xpath="Regelnummer" /></xs:unique></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><rsVoorraad xmlns=""><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test artikel</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Beschadigd</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad2" msdata:rowOrder="1"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test artikel</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Beschikbare voorraad</Type><Aantal>97</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad3" msdata:rowOrder="2"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test artikel</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Gereserveerd</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad4" msdata:rowOrder="3"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test artikel</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>In backorder</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad5" msdata:rowOrder="4"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test artikel</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>In orderverwerking</Type><Aantal>5</Aantal><OrderVoorraad diffgr:id="OrderVoorraad1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><Type>In orderverwerking</Type><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><VariantCode /><Ordernummer>554712</Ordernummer><Regelnummer>1</Regelnummer><Referentie>test decimalen</Referentie><Plaats>Testdorp</Plaats><Leverdatum>2012-02-14T00:00:00+01:00</Leverdatum><Aantal>2</Aantal></OrderVoorraad><OrderVoorraad diffgr:id="OrderVoorraad2" msdata:rowOrder="1"><Type>In orderverwerking</Type><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><VariantCode /><Ordernummer>741124</Ordernummer><Regelnummer>1</Regelnummer><Referentie>test auto mail DHL</Referentie><Plaats>Heerhugowaard</Plaats><Leverdatum>2012-09-07T00:00:00+02:00</Leverdatum><Aantal>1</Aantal></OrderVoorraad></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad6" msdata:rowOrder="5"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test artikel</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Te ontvangen</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad7" msdata:rowOrder="6"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test artikel</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Vrije voorraad</Type><Aantal>100</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad8" msdata:rowOrder="7"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST2</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test 2</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Beschadigd</Type><Aantal>19</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad9" msdata:rowOrder="8"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST2</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test 2</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Beschikbare voorraad</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad10" msdata:rowOrder="9"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST2</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test 2</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Gereserveerd</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad11" msdata:rowOrder="10"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST2</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test 2</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>In backorder</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad12" msdata:rowOrder="11"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST2</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test 2</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>In orderverwerking</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad13" msdata:rowOrder="12"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST2</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test 2</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Te ontvangen</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad><Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad14" msdata:rowOrder="13"><ArtikelCode>WAVETEST2</ArtikelCode><ArtikelGroepCode>ALG</ArtikelGroepCode><Omschrijving>Wave test 2</Omschrijving><VariantCode /><Type>Vrije voorraad</Type><Aantal>0</Aantal></Voorraad></rsVoorraad></diffgr:diffgram></DS><AantRec /></FetchStockResult></FetchStockResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

This is as you can see a wavetest "hello world" return I have to play with on the clients server while getting this working. If anyone could show me how to retrieve for example "ArtikelCode"

or how to get all the "Voorraad diffgr:id="id_name"  would also be excellent

Comment: Well, save for hundreds of questions on stackoverflow with php+simplexml+namespaces to do it by hand... [SneakyFauxSoap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9502553/358679) is nice to debug / get going.

Comment: @Wrikken THANK YOU! I was already trying to change the original input to asXML() and trying to get data from that output but I grabbing $xml as new SimpleXMLElement and not new DOMDocument THEN asXML() > loadXML

I am now able to grab elements!!! so it was all namespaces fault grr lol.  Big thank you, I can't see how I mark your comment as the correct answer though :(  If a moderator see's this then Wrikken is correct.

Comment: Although could you answer one thing

    <Voorraad diffgr:id="Voorraad1" msdata:rowOrder="0">

How do I specify "Voorraad diffgr" ?   like  ->{'Voorraad diffgr'}->  ?

Comment: `diffgr` is the namespace of the attribute (`diffgr:id`), it has nothing to do with addressing `Voorraad` node itself, that _should_ be just `->Voorraad`.

Comment: @Wrikken LOL thank you no where I have been reading mentioned anything about that or I've read so much I totally missed it. Either way Thanks again!  Tested and fully work , big load of my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrikken was quite right, I did not properly understand namespaces and the effect it would have on the output.

After searching again like he suggested I found this question post the most helpful

[PHP Handling Namespace with SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275643/php-handling-namespace-with-simplexml)